# How to have different results for 'list' (players/) and 'detail' (players/{id})?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

Here's the situation. I got a list on my Django REST API: `/playerslist/`

It returns me a list of players just like this one:

http://pastebin.com/JYA39gHT

This is exactly what I want for the moment. But now, I need this:

Going for `/playerslist/1/` gives me different infos for the Player Number 1. The list is here only for listing players with basic informations. But I need detailed view for players, containing info from other models and with different serialization, it must be a basic issue, but as I'm totally new to Django and Python in general, I must misunderstanding something.

Here is my Viewset:

```
class PlayersListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayersListSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['name']

   def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = Player.objects.all()
      team_id = self.request.query_params.get('team', None)

      if team_id:
          try:
              queryset = queryset.filter(team=team_id)
          except ValueError:
              raise exceptions.ParseError()
       return queryset
```

How can I achieve this ? Must I use `@detail_route` to have something like `playerslist/1/detail` ? I've already tried but DRF's documentation only show a single example and it's not clear at all for me.

Comment: Have you checked this? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/ There is example showing retrieve method (for 1 instance) and list method in UserViewSet class. You can declare different serializer for each method.

Comment: This worked like a Charm, I tried this at first, but I must did something wrong I was tired, anyway thanks for your comment, post it as Answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I post it as answer. Im glad It worked for you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the methods retrieve (returning one instance) or list (returning list obviously) as shown in first example in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/.

```
class PlayersListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayersListSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['name']

   def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = Player.objects.all()
      team_id = self.request.query_params.get('team', None)

      if team_id:
          try:
              queryset = queryset.filter(team=team_id)
          except ValueError:
              raise exceptions.ParseError()
       return queryset

   def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       instance = self.get_object()
       serializer = PlayerDetailSerializer(instance)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

Where PlayerDetailSerializer is another serializer with different fields (whatever you need) and there is no need to specify it in serializer_class.

Answer (score 2):

To get different results when you do a 'detail' view, you want to change the serializer when doing a 'retrieve' call. I've done this with a custom mixin for a ModelViewSet, which expects a special "detail_serializer_class":

```
class DifferentDetailSerializerMixin(object):
  """
  For a viewset, mix this in to use a different serializer class
  for individual 'retrieve' views, different from the standard 
  serializer for lists.
  """
  def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      instance = self.get_object()
      serializer = self.detail_serializer_class(instance, context=self.get_serializer_context())
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

Your viewset is simply:

```
class PlayersListViewSet(DifferentDetailSerializerMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayersListSerializer
    detail_serializer_class = PlayersDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['name']
```

Here, PlayersDetailSerializer is another Serializer that has more fields that you want to return.

As an aside, if you want to support optional filtering by teams, I would strongly recommend using django-filter. That way you don't have to worry about validation etc. Once installed, it's simply a case of adding this to your viewset:

```
filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
filter_fields = ['team']
```

See [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) for more info.

Comment: Must I use a custom Mixin ? Can't I simply override the retrieve method in my ViewSet ?

Your solution looks ok, but it looks like it not allow me to use another queryset, right ? (I don't know if I'll need to do this, but I need to know what this way allow me to do.)

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can override the retrieve method directly if you like; i just found this pattern is neater as i found myself needing this quite frequently. Just move that 'retrieve' method down and put it directly in your ViewSet.

Comment: This works like Matúš Bartko way: Overriding retrieve method do the job.

Comment: Um, okay? I gave you working code that answers your question (a custom serialiazer on the retrieve method), an example of a nice mixin to to clarify to your code, a suggestion to smarten up your filtering, and links to further reading. I have no idea how else you could want an answer to your question.

Comment: Your answer is good and working, but I found Markus's one easier to understand for me.